# In tmux, can I show pane titles only when there are multiple panes?

Tags: tmux

I use tmux all the time, but I only use multiple panes in about 20% of my many tmux windows, and the pane status line showing up when there is only one pane is not helpful to me.  I would like to only see it when there are multiple panes, including when I'm zoomed in on one of them (thus reminding me that there are others).

Can I achieve this with any released versions of tmux?  (3.2a at the moment, but if it becomes available in later versions I'm of course still interested in knowing about it.)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to your `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-hook -g -w pane-focus-in "set-option -Fw pane-border-status '#{?#{e|>:#{window_panes},1},top,off}'"
```

It will create a [hook](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#HOOKS) that runs on the `pane-focus-in` event, which calls `set-option` for `pane-border-status`.

The final parameter to `set-option` is a [format string](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#FORMATS) containing a conditional such that, if the current window has more than one pane (`#{window_panes}` > 1), `pane-border-status` is set to the value `top`; else, it is set to the value `off`.

When I test this, windows with a single pane have no pane border/title. When one or more additional panes are created, the border appears:

[image: asciicast]